# Matlab: a smart way to create a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, memory, sparse-matrix

I have to create a matlab matrix that is much bigger that my phisical memory, and i want to take advantage of the sparsity.

This matrix is really really sparse [say N elements in an NxN matrix], and my ram is enought for this. I create the matrix in this way:

A=sparse(zeros(N));

but it goes out of memory. 
Do you know the right way to create this matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zeros(N)` is creating an NxN matrix, which is not sparse, hence you are running out of memory. Your code is equivalent to

```
temp = zeros(N)
A = sparse(temp)
```

Just do `sparse(N,N)`.

Comment: Thank you.Other people wrote me to use A=spalloc(n,n,numelements)

Answer (score 5):

Creating an all zeros sparse matrix, and then modifying it is extremely inefficient in matlab. 
Instead of doing something like:

```
   A = sparse(N,N)  % or even A = sparse([],[],[],N,N,N) 
   A(1:N,7) = 1:N
```

It is much more efficient to construct the matrix in triplet form. That is, 
construct the column and row indices and the nonzero entries first, then 
form the matrix. For example,

```
   i = 1:N;
   j = 7*ones(1,N); 
   x = 1:N;
   A = sparse(i,j,x,N,N);
```

Comment: Can you comment on what "extremely inefficient" means, and perhaps also why it is so?

Comment: zeros(N) will create a dense matrix of all zeros stored in double precision format. This will consume N*N*(8 bytes) of memory. Calling sparse(A) will then remove all zero entries from a matrix. So you are creating a bunch of zeros in memory and then immediately remove them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually recommend the full syntax of sparse([],[],[],N,N,N).

It's useful to preallocate if you know the maximum number of nonzero elements as otherwise you'll get reallocs when you insert new elements.